# Wilcoxon signed rank test or t-test if data is highly skewed?

Tags: t-test, nonparametric, skewness, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have an variable that is highly skewed and I want to test whether my mean is equal to some fix value in another population. I only have the arithmetic mean of the other population. Because I prefer nonparametric statistics and my data is highly skewed, I would perform a Wilcoxon signed rank test. But because I test against an arithmetic mean, I am not quite sure if I should do this. Do you have an idea? I don't want to transform the data.

Comment: Is the other population also skewed or has similar shape? Do you really have only the mean of this other population?

Comment: I don't know. I also have the SD and n, but nothing else.

Comment: But the mean and SD of the other distribution was obtained from the population and not from a sample?

Comment: Testing the mean in a nonparametric way without transforming data - have you considered Monte Carlo approaches such as bootstrapping or permutation tests?

Comment: @Bernhard: How will you do a permutation test with a sample only from one of the populations?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Not at all. If we really have only a sample from one of the populations then we can bootstrap from that one population to estimate the distribution of that populations mean. However, as user2974951's questions abount the other population are not yet answered, I am reluctant to confine possible answers to only bootstrapping. So I mentioned another Monte Carlo method that is suitable to investigate means.

Comment: It was obtained from a sample, too. The analysis is for a client who is not that into statistics, it's for her Bachelor thesis in psychology. I don't think something like bootstrapping is an option for her. Therefore the question could have been which is the smaller evil? I think the signed rank test should be OK.

Comment: Tests are done on samples, not on statistics from a sample, so you will need a different approach.